# Firebase Cloud Functions: HTTPS Callable started throwing error after deployment, error still persists after rolling back

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, https, google-cloud-functions

A few days ago I was making changes to our email notifications code and deploying cloud functions to test. After this one deploy, my application started to throw errors unrelated to the code I was actually working on. This might've been because I was deploying all cloud functions, rather than the one I was working on (a mistake in hindsight).

As a result, there are now two cloud functions in my code that are throwing the same error, both of these are related to authentication but fail immediately when called. The `context` for both of them are now `undefined` in both cases.

> index.js

```
exports.updateUser = functions.https.onCall(lazyLoaded("./src/updateUser"));
```

> /src/updateUser

```
module.exports = async (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) { // CONTEXT IS UNDEFINED HERE
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "failed-precondition",
      "The function must be called while authenticated"
    );
  }
  ...
  // More logic below
  ...
}
```

> Error being thrown

```
Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined
    at module.exports (/workspace/src/updateUser.js:22:16)
    at args (/workspace/index.js:12:56)
    at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:331:32
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Now what's weird is I thought, no big deal, I can just go deploy the latest firebase functions from `master` as a fallback- because I know master hasn't been touched in a few months and I was running out of options.

Even after the rollback, this error is still being thrown in my local as well as the DEV environment. We have 3 other environments though that haven't been touched, and those are working as expected. So basically the code is the same across all the environments at this point, but only DEV is causing issues.

I've tried deleting all the functions from Firebase and redeploying, no luck. When I compare the cloud function environment config files, they are identical except for some keys used for sending emails in the application. I do know that the environment variables for this environment were changed that day, but they were changed a few hours after the issues started to arise. The email keys are completely unrelated to the code that is broken though, so I really don't think the issue is there.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what might be the issue?

Edit (8/17/21):
The issue resolved itself by just redeploying the cloud functions a few days later. Still no explanation behind this resolution as we've been redeploying numerous times. Wondering if there's a cache that got flushed in the meantime.

Comment: There are conditions where that field is null or not present.: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext#auth.    has the triggering event changed?

Comment: @Cadet None of the underlying code has changed which I thought was the weirdest part. Only the cloud functions were changed with new code changes, but after failure, we rolled them back to the existing code. So across all four environments, all code is the same.

Comment: I can't find any npm links with regards to the library you're using. What library are you using for lazyLoaded()? Another question, what happens if you don't lazy load? Are you still getting undefined?

Comment: @RJC lazyLoaded() isn't leveraging a library, it's defined as: `const lazyLoaded = (path) => (...args) => require(path)(...args);` Oddly enough, the Cloud Functions resolved itself after another deploy. Wondering if there's a cache that gets flushed at a certain point. But the issue is now resolved.